# Are mathematical functions "easier" for a neural network to learn?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, function

Say I have a mathematical function that I want a neural network to learn (a realistic and helpful example would be trigonometric `sine()` ). Due to mathematical functions' consistency, as opposed to a data set that has human-related aspects (such as handwritten letters), will neural networks understand and train to a higher degree of success in a lower epoch count when compared to a neural network for, say, digit recognition?

How would training data for something such as `sine()` look like? Would it simply be a random input `n`, and the desired output be `sine(n)`? Or would the training data be similar to something like the MNIST-data set: consisting of a limited amount of constant inputs and desired output that would be run over by several epochs? **Are there any known optimizations for neural networks to learn mathematical functions?**

Thanks

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by a "mathematical function," except that you appear to have in mind something different from the [usual definition.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics))  Could you explain your meaning?

Comment: Sorry I may be wrong.  But actually the question was very clear:   can mathematical functions be emulated by neural network.   And the answer is yes:   sine() is just one dimensional, with the correspond 1D output.   But general problem is multi-dimensional forming a hypersurface, correct?

Comment: same as this:   http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158348/can-a-neural-network-learn-a-functional-and-its-functional-derivative?rq=1