# How bad can the naive derivative estimator be?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, references, nonlinear-regression

Let $f$ be a real valued function defined on a compact set $\mathcal X\subseteq \mathbb R^d $ (and for simplicity let's say $d=1$ for now). We don't know $f$, but can observe it through the (possibly noisy) values $y_1,\ldots,y_n\in\mathbb R $ it takes at some uniformly sampled $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in \mathcal X$. A standard way to estimate $f$ is to let
$$\hat f := \arg\min_{f\in\mathcal F} \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n (f(x_i)-y_i)^2 + \frac\lambda 2 \mathcal P(f) \tag1$$
Where $\mathcal F $ is a family of candidate functions and $\mathcal P$ some penalty. Now, assume that $f$ is smooth (i.e. differentiable many times) and that the functions in $\mathcal F $ are differentiable. If we are interested in computing $f'$,the pointwise derivative of $f$, a naive way to go about it would be to simply set
$$\widehat{f'} := \hat f' \tag2 $$
i.e. simply set our estimate of $f'$ as the pointwise derivative of $\hat f'$ (I call it the *naive derivative estimator*). Now, it is pretty clear that $(2)$ is (in theory at least) a *bad idea* : depending on the noise, the sample size, and our choice of $\mathcal F$, $\hat f$ might be a poor estimate of $f$ already, and even if it weren't, controlling $\|\hat f - f\|_{L^2} $ a priori doesn't tell us anything about $\|\hat f' - f'\|_{L^2} $ (consider a function like $x\mapsto \varepsilon \sin(Mx)$ for small $\varepsilon$ and large $M$).

However, in the literature, there *are* cases where the naive derivative estimator is provably a "good" estimator :

- If $\hat f$ is a [local polynomial estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression), then $\hat f'$ is provably consistent. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/606724/proving-that-the-bias-of-the-derivative-of-parzen-rosenblatt-kernel-density-es?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://www.esaim-ps.org/articles/ps/abs/2014/01/ps140009/ps140009.html), or [here](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/v16/wang15b.html).
- If $\hat f$ is a [smoothing spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing_spline), then again $\hat f'$ is provably consistent. See [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24306706) or [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167947313002193?casa_token=9fWzt_Geby0AAAAA:qEvSY5YoZpi5NPHade1Xk1grbKvFhmU29-PpNjaV5eh2JntE0iqqhjP_MhtkzcwZkNjX-vCh) (and references therein)
- Lastly, if $\hat f$ is a [kernel ridge regression estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method), it can also be proved that $\hat f'$ is consistent, as shown [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.07254) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.01350).

Judging from this, it would seem that if the hypothesis space $\mathcal F$ has been reasonably chosen, $\hat f'$ would *always* be consistent. My question is thus : **are there examples (in the literature) where the least-square estimator (1) is consistent while the naive derivative estimator (2) fails to be consistent ?** In all the literature I've seen so far, $\hat f'$ is always said to have high variance, but nothing about it ever being inconsistent.

Note that I purposefully didn't define "consistent" here (maybe could have used "convergent" instead ?), but think of it as convergence of $\hat f$ to $f$ in some appropriate sense (in probability, in $L^2$, uniformly...) as $n\to\infty$.

---

For context, this question is motivated by [this older one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158348/can-a-neural-network-learn-a-functional-and-its-functional-derivative) about the ability of Neural Networks to simultaneously learn a function and its derivative. My naive intuition is that if the hypothesis space $\mathcal F$ is "good enough" (in the sense that functions in $\mathcal F$ are differentiable and can approximate $f$ well), then the derivative estimator should also be "not too bad". The goal of this question is to check whether that intuition is true or not. (I also have [an open question on this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4593432/when-can-a-neural-network-simultaneously-approximate-a-function-and-its-derivati) over at MSE.)